# Keep delimiter when splitting string

Tags: php, regex

My code below does not keep the delimiter when splitting strings using `preg_split`.

```
$feature_description = "- 1.Read/Write speed performance is based on internal testing.- 2.TBW (terabytes written) values calculated capacity.";


preg_split('/(- [0-9].)/',$feature_description,NULL,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Now the output was:

```
    [0] => - 1.
    [1] => Read/Write speed performance is based on internal testing.
    [2] => - 2.
    [3] => TBW (terabytes written) values calculated capacity.
```

But I want the output as:

```
    [1] => - 1.Read/Write speed performance is based on internal testing.
    [2] => - 2.TBW (terabytes written) values calculated capacity.
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than splitting you should be doing a match using `preg_match_all` using this lookahead based regex:

```
-\h+\d+.+?(?=-\h+\d+|\z)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dn0qLE/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `-\h+\d+`: Match hyphen followed by 1+ horizontal whitespaces and 1+ digits
- `.+?`: Match zero or more of any character (lazy)
- `(?=-\h+\d+|\z)`: Lookahead to assert that we have hyphen followed by 1+ horizontal whitespaces and 1+ digits or end of string

Answer (score 1):

Split with a lookahead:

```
$feature_description = "- 1.Read/Write speed performance is based on internal testing.- 2.TBW (terabytes written) values calculated capacity.";
$res=preg_split('/(?=- [0-9]+\.)/',$feature_description,NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($res);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => - 1.Read/Write speed performance is based on internal testing.
    [1] => - 2.TBW (terabytes written) values calculated capacity.
)
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/E1qAMZ).

Note you no longer need `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` as the regex has no capturing group now.

Note that you need to escape a dot to match a literal dot.

**Pattern details**: `(?=- [0-9]+\.)` is a positive lookahead that matches a location before `-`, a space, 1 or more digits, `.`.

You may enhance the regex a bit like

```
'/\s*(?=-\h[0-9]+\.)/'
```

so as to remove any whitespace between matches (`\s*`) and match any horizontal whitespace between `-` and a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do this:

```
$feature_description = "- 1.Read/Write speed performance is based on internal testing.- 2.TBW (terabytes written) values calculated capacity.";

$feature_description_array = explode("-", $feature_description);//now we have an array broken up by the "-" delmiter
```

Now you should have an array like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.Read/Write speed performance is based on internal testing.
    [1] => 2.TBW (terabytes written) values calculated capacity.
)
```

When printing you could just prepend the missing "-" with

```
echo "- ". Array[0];
```

Comment: Possibly because the strings themselves may include the delimiter `-`.  This would mangle the results.  This case is more reliably served by regex.